# SQLite Versioning Unclear

Tags: database, sqlite, version

If you go to [SQLite's Download page](http://sqlite.org/download.html),
and scroll down to **Precompiled Binaries for Windows**,
you will see that the latest version there (today in 2018) is **3.24.0**.

Yet on many places on the web, I see SQLite being mentioned with version **"3.7.7.1"**,
even in webpages from several years ago..

How can this be?
Those 2 are not relating to the same thing?

Comment: Please link to some example web sites that claim that 3.7.7.1 would be the currently latest version.

Comment: The places where I saw it do not claim that 3.7.7.1 the latest version.. Yet I wonder how can 3.7.7.1 even exist, if the official website is giving 3.24.0 as the latest version. Regarding links: If you google for SQLite 3.7.7.1, you get 835,000 results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite's Version History page](https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html) reveals the answer to the mystery:

The way the creator is counting versions, is like this:
3.7
3.8
3.9
3.10
3.11
3.12
...
...
...
3.24

So v3.24 is higher than v3.7,
different than what we would expect when we look at the numbers in a mathematical form..

Comment: I guess  [Software versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be?

It is because often there is little need to invest in upgrading or that upgrading would carry a significant cost.

> Those 2 are not relating to the same thing?

Basically yes they are the same thing, albeit that obviously the later versions have improvements (see link for more information).

There will be many instances of uses of SQLite3 where updating is not feasible or undertaken for various reasons. So older versions will tend to exist. Many of the millions of uses will be for systems that simply cannot be updated as there is no means of updating.

3.7.7.1 is certainly a valid version of SQLite3 and was available close to 7 years ago.

as per

> 2011-06-28 (3.7.7.1)
>
> 1. Fix a bug causing PRAGMA case_sensitive_like statements compiled using sqlite3_prepare() to fail with an SQLITE_SCHEMA error.
> 2. SQLITE_SOURCE_ID: "2011-06-28 17:39:05 af0d91adf497f5f36ec3813f04235a6e195a605f"
> 3. SHA1 for sqlite3.c: d47594b8a02f6cf58e91fb673e96cb1b397aace0

[Release History](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)

As one example of older version's SQLIte DB Browser, a tool still commonly used, but now unsupported, uses 3.15.2

Comment: Thank you MikeT. But the weird thing here is this: Like you wrote, **v3.7.7.1** is from 2011-06-28. And on the other hand **v3.24.0** is from nowdays, as can be seen in SQLite's Download page..  So how can it be that 3.7.* is from 2011, and 7 years later the version is 3.24.*? They released 3.7.* and then decided to go backwards? Quite illogic.. Either these versions relate to 2 different products, or something here is really unclear.. I hope someone can clarify this..